# Is SQL Server 2016 Standard Edition SP1 support switch partition?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

Is SQL Server 2016 Standard Edition SP1  support switch partition?

We have developed a data archiving process using switch partition mechanism in SQL Server Enterprise Edition.

We want to use the same mechanism in SQL Server Standard edition.  We came to know that partitioning is supported in SQL Server Standard Edition SP1.  But we are not sure whether switch partition is supported in SQL Server Standard edition or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[All editions of SQL Server 2016 SP1 and later](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2017) support the same surface area for table partitioning features, including partition-level `SWITCH`. However, editions besides Enterprise (and Developer) don't support performance features like partitioned table parallelism.

Comment: Note: Documentation says Standard edition supports Partitioned Table Parallelism. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2017?view=sql-server-ver16#:~:text=Partitioned%20Table%20Parallelism